# Free/Libre XMPP client with "Attention" (XEP-0224) support?

Tags: linux, xmpp, open-source

Is there a FLOSS XMPP client for GNU/Linux that supports [XEP-0224: Attention](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0224.html)?

It's an extension for getting the attention of another user. It is also known as ["nudge" or "buzz"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nudge_%28instant_messaging%29).

Answer (score 5):

[Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/) is FOSS, uses the open-source [Libpurple](https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple), and officially supports XEP-0224 through Libpurple.

You can use the `/attention` command. You can also check their [Supported XEPs page](https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/SupportedXEPs) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

[Xabber](http://www.xabber.org/) (free/libre except for the logo, according to a friend) can [do it](https://github.com/redsolution/xabber-android/).

I'm also told [mcabber](http://mcabber.com/) can do it, although the references are sparse; it looks like there is/used to be a plugin needed, and in the current version, the UI marks contacts that want attention from you with an exclamation mark (as opposed to the regular hash sign).

Answer (score 3):

[**Gajim**](https://gajim.org/) seems to support it in its beta version (0.16). (That is why it’s not included in their [list of supported XEPs](https://trac.gajim.org/wiki/GajimXEPSupport) yet.)

The feature was [requested in 2007](https://trac.gajim.org/ticket/3465) and [added in 2012](https://trac.gajim.org/changeset/6d50c40b83de).

You can use it via the `/attention` command.

Note there there is currently some kind of attack possible: [`/attention` vulnerability with notification](https://trac.gajim.org/ticket/7450)